# Pull SQL varbinary(max) to Xamarin image

Tags: c#, sql-server, image, xamarin, binding

I have a Xamarin application that reads images from a SQL Server database, the column that holds the image data index is 4.

I have created a class that contain a member called image, which is an `Image` object.

I have a content page that has a listview. Inside this listview I have an image cell. So, what I want is to to read the image data from the SQL Server database, using the reader, convert the column which is currently being read to a byte array, then convert this byte array to memory stream, then fill the image with this memory stream, then the image which is in the listview will be bound to image int he object , but it looks like I am unable to achieve this. Any help?

Here is the code:

Class file:

```
internal class Attachments
{
    public int serial { get; set; }
    public string attachment_name { get; set; }
    public byte[] image_stream { get; set; }
    public string table_name { get; set; }
    public DateTime create_date { get; set; }
    public string related_serial { get; set; }
    public string created_by { get; set; }
    public Image class_image { get; set; } ? which one to use???
    public StreamImageSource class_source { get; set; }   ? which one to use???
}
```

Xaml file:

```
        <ListView x:Name="images_lv" HasUnevenRows="True">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image Grid.RowSpan="2"
                   Source="{Binding class_source}"
                   Aspect="AspectFill"
                   HeightRequest="60"
                   WidthRequest="60" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

`Xaml.cs` file:

```
private async void get_image_from_db()
{
    List<Classes.Attachments> attachments = new List<Classes.Attachments>();
        
    string conn = "Server=******; database=******; user id=******; password=*****";
    string query = "select * from Attachments";

    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conn);

    try
    {
        connection.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            ms.Position = 0;

            int serial = reader.GetInt32(0);
            string attachemnt_name = reader.GetString(1);
            string table_name = reader.GetString(2);
            DateTime createdate = reader.GetDateTime(3);

            byte[] media = reader.GetSqlBytes(4).Value;
            ms.Write(media,0, media.Length);

            string related_serial = reader.GetString(5);
            string created_by = reader.GetInt32(6).ToString() ;

            attachments.Add(new Classes.Attachments
                    {
                        serial = serial,
                        attachment_name = attachemnt_name,
                        image_stream = media,
                        related_serial = related_serial,
                        created_by = created_by,
                        create_date = createdate,
                        class_source = (StreamImageSource)ImageSource.FromStream(() => ms),
                        class_image = new Image().Source()

                        //class_image.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => ms)
                    }) ;
        }

        images_lv.ItemsSource = attachments;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        await DisplayAlert("", ex.ToString(), "");
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: you should be able to make this work, but if I were you I would write the image stream to a file and then store the file path in my model.  Then you can just bind to the file path

Comment: Thank you Jason. But in my code, how can I fill the image element with the memory stream (ms), each loop in the (while) statement? If I used your suggestion, if I understood it correctly, I have to loop again through the objects to fill the image with the file data.

Comment: Side note: your connection and command need `using`

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason to use an intermediate byte[], and after you write to the MemoryStream you have to rewind the stream again.

```
  byte[] media = reader.GetSqlBytes(4).Value;
  ms.Write(media,0, media.Length);
```

to

```
  reader.GetStream(4).CopyTo(ms);
  ms.Position=0;
```

Comment: Thank you David for this comment, and execuse me for being new at c#. In my above code, am I filling the image element (class_source) correctly? Because when I run the app, the listview is empty!

Comment: I don't know anything about Xamarin.

Comment: Thanks David. I don't know if this is Xamarin or c# specific, but is it doable configuring an element which is inside an object while looping? And how can this be done in c#? Thanks again.